# What concept would be independent of path and how do I state it?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Below are lists of theorems I have studied:

> **Theorem1**. Let $x,z_0\in S^1\times \mathbb{C}$ and $f,g:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$ be coninuous functions and $\alpha$ is a loop in $S^1$ whose path-homotopy class $[\alpha]$(homotopy class relative to $\{0,1\}$) is not the identity. Then, $f\simeq g$ iff $Wnd(f\circ \alpha, z_0)=Wnd(g\circ \alpha, z_0)$.

${}$

> **Theorem2**. Let $C$ be a simple closed curve in $S^2$ and $p,q$ be points lying in different connected components of $S^2\setminus C$. Then, the inclusion map $j:C\hookrightarrow S^2\setminus\{p,q\}$ induces a group isomorphism of the fundamental groups.

${}$

> **Theorem3**. Let $\alpha$ be a simple loop in $\mathbb{C}$. If $z_0$ lies in the exterior of $f(I)$, then $Wnd(\alpha,z_0)=0$. If it lies in the interior of $f(I)$, then $Wnd(\alpha,z_0)=±1$.

I think these theorems say something about independence of paths which I don't know how to interpret.

I don't know multivariable calculus, but I remember I have seen a theorem "a line integral is independence of path".  However, the standard definition of line integration requires a path to be differentiable which is too strong.

I think above two theorems would make it legit to write $\int_C $ instead of $\int_{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is a simple loop and $C$ is a simple closed curve.

What would be this concept?

And is there a text explaining that concept well?

Comment: There's a little book by Singer and Thorpe -- something like "Elementary Concepts of Geometry and Topology"  --- that sits right in the middle of the kinds of topics you're asking about. Alas, it requires that you know at least some multivariable calculus. Some things, esp. in math, do come in a certain order.

Comment: @JohnHughes I refuse to study something assuming other things I haven't proven. (For example, I would not study Green's theorem if I haven't proven Jordan curve theorem so that I don't know what is a counterclockwise loop) That's why I haven't studied multivariable calculus.. I have studied Frechet and Gateau derivatives in Banach space context, but nothing about Green or Stoke's theorems. Would it suffice the preliminaries? And thank you.

Comment: @JohnHughes I have skimmed the book but cannot find which chapter your meant.. Would you tell me which chapter contains these concepts?

Comment: No...you really need to know something about path integrals, for instance. As for "which parts use this stuff", by the tail end of the book -- around p. 148, when you're proving deRham's theorem, you'll have everything you need to know to relate integration over paths and homotopy of paths. To apply it to $\mathbb C$ requires a little more work, but not too much. Still, since this book relies on the triangulability of smooth compact manifolds, but does not prove it, you probably don't want to read it. Best of luck in finding a better alternative.